# Ошибка MySQL на Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Добрый день. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с проблемой. Есть свежоустановленная MySQL 5.7 но не могу подключится. Выходит такая ошибка.

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2). Заранее благодарен.

Comment: а вы ее запустили ? что то типа `/etc/init.d/mysql start` или как у вас в юбунту сервисы обычно стартуют. Не помешает еще логи посмотреть где нибудь в районе /var/log/mysql

Comment: Она вообще даже не запускается. Когда пишу mysql. Там в логах в конфиге и в сокетах все нормально вроде бы

Comment: рассказывайте, как и что именно вы «свежеустановили». прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: @Ashot, "Когда пишу mysql" - а надо запускать `sudo service mysql start` и смотреть что оно скажет.

Comment: @PinkTux так пишу, говорит Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service is masked

Comment: @alexanderbarakin все свежоустановлено )) начиная с убунту

Comment: @Ashot, процесс установки дистрибутива, конечно, не нужно описывать. а вот процесс, в результате которого у вас «Есть свежоустановленная MySQL 5.7» — интересует. изложите, пожалуйста, этот процесс **прямо в тексте вопроса**.

Comment: Установку mysql делал по пунктам написанным в digital ocean

Comment: @Ashot, если вы настаиваете на том, чтобы читающие ваш вопрос сами догадывались о последовательности ваших действий, то так тому и быть. будем ждать появления телепата-добровольца.

Answer (score 1):

В 95% случаев такая ошибка выводится, когда MySQL-сервер не запущен. Проверить так ли это, можно воспользовавшись командой

```
ps aux | grep mysqld
```

Если сервер не запущен, то запустить его в Ubuntu можно при помощи команды

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Если это не приводит к запуску, искать причину следует в логах ошибок /var/log/mysql/error.log и /var/log/mysql.err

Comment: Спасибо. Буду копать )

Comment: error.log пуст а mysql.err нету

Comment: А процесс запущен?

Comment: Сервер не запускается failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service is masked